# how to parse for specific text?

Tags: java, android, dom, jsoup

I want to use jsoup just to parse the middle text telling you about the title.

http://www.upcominggames.com/2113/Halo+Combat+Evolved+Anniversary/
  http://www.upcominggames.com/478/Gears+of+War+3/

What would the jsoup tags be to parse this and extract just the article?

What would be a common selector for the two articles above?

EDIT:

What i want to do is parse this part

**Gears of War 3 Facts**
    Gears of War 3 is a third-person shooter published by Microsoft and developed by Epic Games, and it is set to be released on September 20, 2011 in the US, Australian and Europe and on September 22 in Japan.

**Gears of War 3 Synopsis**

    This Xbox 360 exclusive conclusion to the Gears of War trilogy, Gears of War 3 places players in the middle of an exciting experience and story of survival, hope and brotherhood. This third-person shooter dramatically leads players through the exciting world with more color and detail than ever before. Plus, its exciting multiplayer mode will lead players wanting more even after they’ve finished the campaign.

**Gears of War 3 Gameplay**
    Anyone who has played a Gears of War game will feel familiar when they play Gears of War 3, but that doesn’t meant they won’t be faced with a few new surprised. The environments are much more detailed and immersive, adding to the excitement and thrill the Gears of War franchise is known for. Featuring more enemies than previous installments of the Gears of War series, Gears of War 3 will offer players a brand new challenge as they try to save the human race from complete destruction. If players own a 3D TV, they’ll be able to play this new installment in 3D to have a completely immersive experience.

**Gears of War 3 Multiplayer**
    The multiplayer additions to Gears of War 3 make the game a big step up from Gears of War 2. Starting with dedicated servers to handle matchmaking, Epic Games has put a lot of effort into making this the best Gears experience yet. With Capture the Leader, King of the Hill and other multiplayer modes, players will be able to take their game online against other players in exciting deathmatches.

I want to parse the Bold into a seperate textView and then under it i want to load its content. 
Basically just how it is above.

If you hilight the text  and click view selection source youll see what i trying to parse

I am familiar with jsoup. Just need some help on this part.

Comment: "to parse the middle text telling you about the title" -- could you explain a bit more just what you're trying to do here?

Comment: YOu get what i am saying now?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of things that you have tried?  If you have not put forth any effort in doing this, it is not likely to garner much attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I get what you're saying.  I think that Jsoup would easily extract this if you study the web page source code and find common linking tags and attributes. Ones to try include:

- get the Elements that have the tag "div"
- the attribute "id" that is assigned "game-desc"

The text returned from just these two filters will likely get you what you want.

e.g.,

**Edit: code simplified to use select(...)**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HaloStuff {
   private static final String TEST_URL_1 = "http://www.upcominggames.com/" +
        "2113/Halo+Combat+Evolved+Anniversary/";
   private static final String DIV_TAG = "div";
   private static final String ID_ATTR = "id";
   private static final String GAME_DESC = "game-desc";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Document jsDoc = null;

      List<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();

      try {
         jsDoc = Jsoup.connect(TEST_URL_1).get();

         Elements textEles = jsDoc.select("div[id=game-desc]");
         for (Element ele : textEles) {
            System.out.println(ele.text());
         }

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.. Okay so i understand jsoup alot better from your code snippet! Thanks alot. Also how could i format the bold parts to be in there own text and have the article content under each bold section?  like in the halo article.

Comment: "This is left as an exercise for the reader." In other words, give it a try yourself as it's not hard to do. Play with your code.

Comment: Okay thanks alot. Im sure i can figure it out. Just with your help it would be quicker. lol

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do it with:

```
div#game-desc p
```

What have you tried that's not working?